# How to debug an error in VLC for Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-app, logcat, vlc, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I have a chrome app that mounts a filesystem in Chrome OS.

When I try to run a movie from that drive, I get the following error from VLC:

> Playback error
>
> VLC encountered an error with this media.
>
> Please try refreshing the media library.
>
> The location file:///data/data/org.chromium.arc/external/[Some_ID]/[File_Name] cannot be played.

I tried enabling logcat in the inspection window with:

```
plugin.shell('logcat');
```

but it didn't catch any errors.

How can I debug why this generic error has occurred in VLC?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I can see the file using the following command:

```
plugin.shell("ls -l '/data/data/org.chromium.arc/external/[Some_ID]/[File_Name]'");
```

I get the following answer:

> -------- 0 root gr0 0 Jan 01 02:00 /data/data/org.chromium.arc/external/[Some_ID]/[File_Name]

Comment: The question should explicitly state that this file is playable elsewhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm actually it isn't. I just found out that playing movies from a mounted zip don't work either.